# Как задать начальные значения в определении структуры?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```
struct hdrs{
    string sdr1;  //string sdr1="1"; ? Но компилятор так ругается
};
/////
hdrs myhdrs; //myhdrs.sdr1 должен равняться "1"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

О конструкторах что-нибудь слышали?

```
struct hdrs
{
    string sdr1;

    hdrs() : sdr1("1") { }

    hdrs(const string& value) : sdr1(value)  { }
};
```

Comment: @DreamChild, хм, я думал конструкторы есть только у классов

Comment: Вы случайно не с Паскаля начинали? Я вас, возможно, удивлю, но у структур могут быть и функции-члены, и конструкторы, к которым даже можно применять ограничения видимости. Разница между классами и структурами кое в чем другом

Comment: @ололо я сам начинал с него же, и, если не ошибаюсь, именно оттуда пошло заблуждение, что у структур могут быть только поля. Возможно для Паскаля это верно, (а может и неверно, не помню уже) но в С++/C# структуры отличаются от классов не отсутствием методов и конструкторов

Answer (score 0):

```
myhdrs.sdr1 = "value";
```

Ну или добавьте конструктор по умолчанию.

```
public hdrs(const std::string& val):sdr1(val) {
}
```

Также учтите что в списке инициализации все проперти инициализируются строго в том порядке, в котром они идут в объявлении класса.

Comment: @SoloMio, нужно это сделать в определении струтуры